# How to extract src/link image from a RSS Feed using JSP

Tags: xml, jsp, rss, aem

I am trying to create an Adobe CQ component where I take information from the rss feed link / xml file. Using a foreach I can have access to the data but my problem is that I need to extract the src attribute from the image tag in order to add classes.

I have this:

```
<c:forEach var="feed" items="${list}" varStatus="vs">
 ${feed.image}
</c:forEach>
```

I want to do this:

```
<c:forEach var="feed" items="${list}" varStatus="vs">
 <img src="${feed.image[src]}" alt=""/>
</c:forEach>
```

I tried that already and as result I have unknown:

```
<img src=unknown alt=""/>
```

Comment: Does `${feed.image.src}` works?

Comment: @SandeepKumar No that doesn't works I found the solution looking for strings before and after.

Answer (score 0):

I found that as solution:

```
<c:set var="beginSrc" value='src="' />
<c:set var="endSrc" value='"' />
<c:set var="wpImgStrg1" value="${feed.image}" />
<c:set var="wpImgStrg2" value="${fn:substringAfter(wpImgStrg1, beginSrc)}" />
<c:set var="wpImgStrg" value="${fn:substringBefore(wpImgStrg2, endSrc)}"/> 
<img src="${wpImgStrg}" class="block" />
```